# Set background image in JEditorPane from local file

Tags: java, css, swing

I am using JEditorPane to set background image on my JFrame. The reason why I use this component, is that I want to set small image and be able to repeat it according to size of the frame. Similar to CSS analogue of background-repeat. The problem which I have is, I am not able to load image from my local folder.

```
background.setContentType("text/html");
background.setText("<html><body style=\"background-image: url(http://hq-wallpapers.ru/wallpapers/8/hq-wallpapers_ru_abstraction3d_39318_1920x1200.jpg);\"></body></html>");
  this.setContentPane(background);
```

What I tried is to use: url(../image.jpg); but it doesn't work.

If can offer better way of doing this task, I will appreciate it.
P.S.: And I am not allowed to use JFrameForm, because of requirements of my project.

Comment: Where is the code that loads the local file?

Comment: @user1803551 I follow web development logic, simply change background style of .setText() method. So I have smth like this: background.setText("<html><body style=\"background-image: url(../src/images/hq-wallpapers_ru_abstraction3d_39318_1920x1200.jpg);\"></body></html>");

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. Local folder usually means one in the resources of the project. You're loading a file from the internet, which is not considered "local".

Comment: @user1803551 I know, I do load image from internet, but what I try to achieve is change it to local storage. I still want to use HTML way of doing it. The reason why, because It repeats image and I can use small 10px by 10px picture to fill my background. I was trying to find solution in the Web, where I can use standart Swing elements to fill background with small image, but I couldn't find any suitable idea.

Comment: Did MadProgammer not solve this then?

Comment: @user1803551 he did, I just didn't have time to check the code immediately. It works as I wanted.

Comment: Good to hear! Come again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`../image.jpg` isn't a valid URL, as the `JEditorPane` has no "code base" from which to access where the "reference" should be loaded from.

Instead, you could use a `File` to generate a `URL` (or if it's an embedded resource, `Class#getResource`), for example...

```
File background = new File("../image.jpg");
URL url = background.toURI().toURL();

ep.setContentType("text/html");
ep.setText("<html><body style='color: #ffffff; background-image: url(" + url.toString() + ");'>Boo</body></html>");
```

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane();

                File background = new File("/Volumes/Disk02/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/Aqua/aria_fanart_by_imskeptical-d5xbvgz.jpg");
                URL url = background.toURI().toURL();

                ep.setContentType("text/html");
                ep.setText("<html><body style='color: #ffffff; background-image: url(" + url.toString() + ");'>Boo</body></html>");
                add(new JScrollPane(ep));
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Now if `URL url = background.toURI().toURL();` doesn't work, you might need to use `URL url = background.getCanonicalFile().toURI().toURL();` instead